# Regex to replace only single line breaks with br but NOT inside specific HTML tags

Tags: php, regex

I have some text whereby I need to replace only single line breaks (`\n`) with a `<br />`, but not when followed/preceded by another line break or carriage return (`\r\n` or `\r \n` or `\n \n` or `\n\n`)

According to another answer, I can use regex `(\S.*?)\R(.*?\S)` with replace as $1
$2.

This works great, however I need to avoid using this when inside certain tags such as `<ul>, <h2> and <blockquote>`

How can I modify the regex to avoid specific tags?

Comment: Edited to incorporate other answer and ask refined question